# pdo driver does not suport transactions on linux

Tags: php, sql-server, transactions, pdo

I've been using the DBLib PDO driver for connecting my PHP Symfony project with the MsSQL Database (where I need to query only 2 tables, Propel is set to connect with the MySQL database, which is main)

Unfortunately, I encountered problem, when a need to use transaction occured.

the following code

```
$pdo = new PDO('dblib:host=IP;dbname=DBNAME', 'login', 'password');
$pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo -> beginTransaction();
$sql = "INSERT INTO DBNAME (Fields) VALUES (Values) ";
$query = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
$query -> execute();
$sql = "SELECT Field FROM DBNAME";
$query = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
$query -> execute();
$dane1 = $query -> fetchAll();
$pdo -> rollBack();
$sql = "SELECT Field FROM DBNAME";
$query = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
$query -> execute();
$dane2 = $query -> fetchAll();
```

I get such an error:

```
PDOException Object ( [message:protected] => This driver doesn't support transactions [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0
```

I've been looking for any other driver that would support the transaction, but unfortunately, i Couldn't find anything except [Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098), which doesn't apply to my issue, because my project is working on LAMP environment

Comment: are you using MyISAM, or InnoDB, or something else?

Comment: For MySQL i'm using InnoDB, but the issue is according to Microsoft SQL Server Database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use PHP 5.4, transaction support was added for `PDODblib`

Alternatively, you could copy the `pdodblib` files from 5.4 source to 5.3 and compile (they are nearly identical) or execute manual transaction queries.

Comment: after a little struggle with a customer - I have upgraded php to 5.4 and problem ceased to exist. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There has been a long lasting bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38955

The SqlServ driver works indeed flawlessly on Windows. For Linux you should connect via ODBC (using FreeTDS) as mentioned in the php docs [here](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-dblib.php) and [especially here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php).